# Do not understand condition flags on ARM Cortex M4

Tags: arm

I am having trouble understanding why certain xPRS condition flags are being set.

Here is the code (I have commented on the xPRS flag values):

```
MOVS R0, #0            ; n=0 z=1 c=0 v=0
MOVS R1, #1            ; n=0 z=0 c=0 v=0
MVNS R2, #0            ; n=1 z=0 c=0 v=0
MOVS R3, #0x80000000   ; n=1 z=0 c=1 v=0
MOVS R4, R0            ; n=0 z=1 c=1 v=0
MOVS R5, R1            ; n=0 z=0 c=1 v=0
MOVS R6, R2            ; n=0 z=1 c=1 v=0
```

The part I have problems understanding are from line 4 onwards (MOVS R3, #0x80000000).

The ARM user guide says that "When an Operand2 constant is used with the instructions MOVS, MVNS, ANDS, ORRS, ORNS, EORS, BICS, TEQ or TST, the carry flag is updated to bit[31] of the constant, if the constant is greater than 255 and can be produced by shifting an 8-bit value. These instructions do not affect the carry flag if Operand2 is any other constant."

This is fine, so the reason the C flag is on is due to 0x80000000 having bit[31] as a 1, which in turn sets the C flag to 1.

However I also have the N flag on, so I thought that bit[31] could also the sign, so maybe 0x80000000 is actually representing -0 ( bit[31] which is the sign being a 1, the rest 0's which is the number, but the Z flag is not on, so this cant be the case? so why is it N but not Z?

Thanks

Comment: Like just about any other architecture these days, all ARM arithmetic is two's complement: 0x80000000 is -2147483648, which is definitely not zero.

Comment: OK so maybe what I have read have just confused me then! so I need to add another bit on for the sign, which makes over 32 bits in length now, which is why it carried? I will have a look into two's complement again I think!

Comment: Er, that's not how [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) works. You're apparently thinking of a sign-magnitude representation, which is not at all commonly used (for integers) in the current century...

Comment: Fair enough thanks, least I know what I need to look up to understand this. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: so, have I understood this correctly? 0x80000000 in binary is 10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000, but as its twos compliment, the 1 does not get counted as 2^32 but instead as 2^-32 which is -2147483648. so that explains the N flag, any idea why C flag is on?

Comment: I think it's mostly "Because the architecture says so." by now. As the quote in the question alludes to, this kind of immediate is encoded in the instruction as an 8-bit value and an amount to rotate it by - historically, that rotation used the barrel shifter like any other ALU operation, thus causing some flags to fall out. Regardless of whether modern cores might be cleverer at decoding immediates, the precedent is set for the _visible_ behaviour to stay the same (see also the now-largely-meaningless 2-instruction PC offset for a similar example).